Keras: Relationship extraction
I am trying to manage how to extract logical relations from medical sentences. E.g.:
INPUT: "Candidiasis is infection by Candida species (most often C. albicans), manifested by mucocutaneous lesions, fungemia, and sometimes focal infection of multiple sites."
OUTPUT: "Candidiasis – infection" "Candidiasis – Candida species (most often C. albicans)" "Candidiasis – mucocutaneous lesions" "Candidiasis – fungemia" "Candidiasis – focal infection"
How this type of problem is called and what architechtures should I use for solving it?
I read that this problem is somehow related with POS-tagging, but I cannot figure how make model search relations for each word in a sentence.
